# Не могу запустить скрипт на js

Tags: javascript, mysql

Код скрипта

```
const { strict } = require("assert/strict");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({host: "localhost", user: "user", database: "database", password: "password"});

var sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename;';
connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
});

connection.end;
```

Это код ошибки

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'assert/strict'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/v1nc3nt_one1ll/Desktop/Template by/sql.js:1:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Была попытка исправить ошибку вот так `npm install assert` и `npm install assert/strict` но результат не изменился

> Ну а что говорит "npm install" ? Вообще в таких ситуациях желательно линковать ещё "package.json"

```
$ npm install assert
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/v1nc3nt_one1ll/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/v1nc3nt_one1ll/package.json'
npm WARN inspectable@1.2.0 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN v1nc3nt_one1ll No description
npm WARN v1nc3nt_one1ll No repository field.
npm WARN v1nc3nt_one1ll No README data
npm WARN v1nc3nt_one1ll No license field.

+ assert@2.0.0
updated 1 package and audited 257 packages in 2.447s

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Ну а что говорит "npm install" ? Вообще в таких ситуациях желательно линковать ещё "package.json"

Comment: Вообще ответ на твой вопрос уже есть на Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49636982/strict-mode-using-assert-module-in-nodejs

Comment: @Eugene-X, спасибо. справил первую строку на `const { strict } = require("assert").strict;` и все заработало